# Java/Android Studio mkdirs() returns false with (requested) WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission

Tags: java, android-studio

I am trying to make a folder to store a database backup on the device itself, using mkdirs(). However, it keeps failing on making the folder to store this backup in and I am not sure why.

I checked wether I have permission to write, if the directory already exists, wether the directories match and the state of the external storage but somehow mkdirs() only returns false.

```
public class BackupActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_PATH = "data/com.example.myapplication/databases/";
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "DatabaseName";
    private static final String BACKUP_FOLDER_NAME = "BackupFolder";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.d("Backup", "Wel toestemming");
            try {
                createBackup();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("Backup", "" + e.getMessage());
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("Backup", "Geen toestemming");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }

        finish();
    }

    public static void createBackup() throws IOException {
        if(!canBackup()) {
            Log.d("Backup", "!canBackup");
            throw new IOException("Backup kan niet worden opgeslagen");
        }

        File backupFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), BACKUP_FOLDER_NAME);
        Log.d("Backup", "External storage dir: " + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
        Log.d("Backup", "External storage state: " + Environment.getExternalStorageState());
        Log.d("Backup", "Backup Folder path: " + backupFolder.getPath());

        if (!backupFolder.exists()) {
            Log.d("Backup", "mkdirs()");

            if(backupFolder.mkdirs()) {
                backupFolder.mkdirs();
                Log.d("Backup", "Geslaagd" + backupFolder.mkdirs());
            } else {
                Log.e("Backup", "Gefaald: " + backupFolder.getAbsolutePath());
                try {
                    throw new IOException("Dir maken gefaald");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.e("Backup", "Gefaald: " + e.getMessage());

                }
            }
        }

        if (backupFolder.canWrite()) {
            Log.d("Backup", "Backup folder goed");
        } else {
            Log.e("Backup", "Backup folder fout");
        }

        File database = new File(Environment.getDataDirectory(), DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME);
        FileInputStream databaseInputStream = new FileInputStream(database);
        Log.d("Backup", "Database path: " + database.getPath());


        File databaseBackup = new File(backupFolder, DATABASE_NAME + ".bak");
        FileOutputStream databaseOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(databaseBackup);
        Log.d("Backup", "Backup db path: " + databaseBackup.getPath());


        FileChannel dbSource = databaseInputStream.getChannel();
        FileChannel dbDestination = databaseOutputStream.getChannel();
        dbDestination.transferFrom(dbSource, 0, dbSource.size());

        dbSource.close();
        dbDestination.close();
        databaseInputStream.close();
        databaseOutputStream.close();
    }

    private static boolean canBackup() {
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        return Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state);
    }
}
```

I expect the above code to print and create the directory BackupFolder. Instead it errors and shows that mkdirs() and the canWrite returns false. How can I check what exactly causes the failure of mkdirs()?

Comment: **tl;dr** you can't access "general files" when targeting recent SDK versions with some very specific exceptions. [Read all about it here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage).

Comment: So from my understanding, what I want to do is not possible anymore? Are there any alternatives?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage#all-files-access